# How to use order_by in one to many relationship in flask depending on a condition

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, one-to-many

I have two models question and answers in relationship , I can query a specific question and then print it's answers but I want to know how to order the answers by one of their column

I read many SO questions but they define it when creating the table, but I want to order the answers on condition, `votes` or `date` like here on stackoverflow,

```
class Question(db.Model):
    sno = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100))
    ans =  db.relationship("Answers",backref="owner")

class Answers(db.Model):
    ans_no = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    answer = db.Column(db.String(3000))
    votes = db.Column(db.Integer(),default=0)
    date = db.Column(db.String(15))
    ques_id =  db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("question.sno"))
```

I want something like

```
q1 = Question.query.filter_by(sno=1).first()
q1.ans // gives me [<Answers1>,<Answers3>] so on
```

How can I order the `q1.ans` on basis of votes or date. any suggestions would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always would like this to be the case, just add [`order_by=date`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.order_by) to your relationship definition.

Otherwise, just perform a separate query:

```
sorted_anwers = Answer.query.where(with_parent(q1, Answer.owner)).order_by(Answer.votes.desc())
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I was thinking if there was another way so that I don't have to make a new query. I can order the `ans` feild when making the query for Question. Is it possible

Comment: See the link in the answer to https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.order_by